# Как отправить информацию не отдельными сообщениями, а одним сообщением в Телеграм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Как отправить информацию не отдельными сообщениями, а одним сообщением в Телеграм боте?

У меня есть обработчик словаря, который отправляет названия наиближайших мест из словаря смотря на геопозицию пользователя.

```
def uz_shop_view(message: telebot.types.Message) -> None:
  if message.location is not None:
    lon: float = message.location.longitude
    lat: float = message.location.latitude

    distance: List[...] = []
    for loc in STORES:
      result: float = geodesic(
      (loc['lons'], loc['lats']), (lon, lat)).meters
      distance.append(result)
      counter = len(distance)
    while counter > 0:
      i = distance.index(min(distance))
      print(i)
      distance[i] = 10 ** 100
      counter -= 1
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f' ' + '<b>'+STORES[i]['title']+'</b>' + '\n\n' + '<i>'+STORES[i]['address']+'</i>', parse_mode='html')
```

Но каждое место отправляется отдельными сообщениями. Как сделать так чтобы они пришли одним сообщением?

библиотеки: telebot, geopy

Answer (score 0):

Всё мне помогло вот это:

```
def uz_shop_view(message: telebot.types.Message) -> None:
    if message.location is not None:
        text = ''
        lon: float = message.location.longitude
        lat: float = message.location.latitude

        distance: List[...] = []
        for loc in STORES:
            result: float = geodesic(
            (loc['lons'], loc['lats']), (lon, lat)).meters
            distance.append(result)
            counter = len(distance)
        while counter > 0:
            i = distance.index(min(distance))
            distance[i] = 10 ** 100
            counter -= 1
            text += STORES[i]['title']
            text += '\n' + STORES[i]['address'] + '\n\n'
            print(text)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```